# A question about windows iocp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, iocp

When I write a program about IO completion port in Windows Vista,
the first sample didn't work and the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() can not get 
any OVERLAPPED structures.

So I put the OVERLAPPED structure in global scope,and it works amazingly.
Why is that?

CODE1:

```
int main()
{
    OVERLAPPED o;
    ..
    CreateIoCompletionPort(....);

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        WriteFile(..,&o);

        OVERLAPPED* po;
        GetQueuedCompletionStatus(..,&po);
    }


}
```

CODE2:

```
OVERLAPPED o;

int main()
{

    ..
    CreateIoCompletionPort(....);

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        WriteFile(..,&o);

        OVERLAPPED* po;
        GetQueuedCompletionStatus(..,&po);
    }


}
```

Comment: Edited my post sometime back. You may want to take a second look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay! This is from the [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342(VS.85).aspx) structure's MSDN page's Remarks section:

> Any unused members of this structure should always be initialized to zero before the structure is used in a function call. Otherwise, the function may fail and return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Globals are zero initializes whereas locals are not. If you plan to use the former code, you need to zero out the memory:

```
int main() {
    OVERLAPPED o = {0}; 
    // ...
```

Comment: In the former program, the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() just wait there until time is out. It seems there 's no way I can call GetLastError().